# How to infer parquet schema by hive table schema without inserting any records?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

Now given a hive table with its schema, namely:

```
hive> show create table nba_player;
OK
CREATE TABLE `nba_player`(
  `id` bigint, 
  `player_id` bigint, 
  `player_name` string, 
  `admission_time` timestamp, 
  `nationality` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://endpoint:8020/user/hive/warehouse/nba_player'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1541140811')
Time taken: 0.022 seconds, Fetched: 16 row(s)
```

How to infer its parquet schema without inserting any records?

The parquet schema is like:

```
message_meta
{optional int64 id;
 optional int64 player_id;
 optional binary player_name;
 optional timestamp admission_time;
 optional binary nationality;}
```

Comment: Found a solution when reading hive source code. @see org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.convert.HiveSchemaConverter#convert()

Comment: How have you use the HiveSchemaConverter ? could it be applied for the vice versa ? Meaning to infer hive schema based on parquet schema ?

Comment: @dumitru I'm not sure, maybe you need to check the logic of HiveSchemaConverter and do some reverse engineering? I leave the code below, hope to be useful

Answer (score 0):

The code is shown as below

```java
    /**
     * Generate MessageType by table properties using HiveSchemaConverter
     *
     * @param tableProperties {@link Properties}
     * @return MessageType
     */
    public static MessageType getMessageTypeFromTable(final Properties tableProperties) {

        final String columnNameProperty = tableProperties.getProperty(IOConstants.COLUMNS);
        final String columnTypeProperty = tableProperties.getProperty(IOConstants.COLUMNS_TYPES);
        List<String> columnNames;
        List<TypeInfo> columnTypes;

        if (columnNameProperty.length() == 0) {
            columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        } else {
            columnNames = Arrays.asList(columnNameProperty.split(","));
        }

        if (columnTypeProperty.length() == 0) {
            columnTypes = new ArrayList<TypeInfo>();
        } else {
            columnTypes = TypeInfoUtils.getTypeInfosFromTypeString(columnTypeProperty);
        }

        MessageType messageType = HiveSchemaConverter.convert(columnNames, columnTypes);
        logger.info("messageType is inferred to be: {}", messageType.toString());
        return messageType;
    }
```

```java
public class ParquetHelperTest {

    @Test
    public void testGenerateParquetSchemaFromTableProperties() {
        Properties tableProperties = new Properties();
        tableProperties.setProperty(IOConstants.COLUMNS, "id,player_id,player_name,admission_time,nationality");
        tableProperties.setProperty(IOConstants.COLUMNS_TYPES, "bigint,bigint,string,timestamp,string");
        MessageType messageType = ParquetHelper.getMessageTypeFromTable(tableProperties);

        String expectedMessageType = "message hive_schema {\n"
            + "  optional int64 id;\n"
            + "  optional int64 player_id;\n"
            + "  optional binary player_name (UTF8);\n"
            + "  optional int96 admission_time;\n"
            + "  optional binary nationality (UTF8);\n"
            + "}";

        String calculatedMessageType = messageType.toString();
        calculatedMessageType = calculatedMessageType.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        expectedMessageType = expectedMessageType.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        Assert.assertTrue(calculatedMessageType.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedMessageType));
    }
}
```